# How to install a pkg in 14.04 after failed repeated attempts following different approaches?

Tags: 14.04, package-management

This is to ask, How does one start over, with a clean slate, to install a software package in 14.04, after having made several previous attempts to install following conflicting advice from the web?

I have run:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge wine*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package wine-src
```

I have also run synaptic, and inside it, have run:

```
Edit->Fix Broken Packages
```

and

```
Settings->Filters->Broken->OK
```

neither of which gave perceptible feedback of having done anything.

```
alt@alfred:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
alt@alfred:~$
```

[Thank you, L.D. James, for the gift of your time in the chat room. As you said, it's incredible that the steps I took didn't resolve it. I'm going to reinstall, but I'm going to ask another question too, as a result.]

[Later edit: I would like to add that packages I added were done from the command line, with apt-get, using mundane, version-less, pkg-names. It may be that at some point I also added a package I found via Ubuntu Software Center. **I assumed that apt-get and USC know about, and respect, each other's installs.** It may be that this is the source of my ultimate failure.]

Comment: Programs are installed either using the Ubuntu-Software GUI application.  Type in the name of the software you want to install and follow the prompts.  From the commandline you run `sudo apt [software name]`.  If you have a problem you would have to address any issue according to the output.  If you have done something different, that is probably your culprit.  We can't just infer what you have done without some details of what you have done and the errors you are getting.  When using the methods I mentioned, the system will display how to correct problems it might have.

Comment: I regret that you interpreted what I wrote to be a request for you to infer anything.  What I have done is to "use the Ubuntu-Software GUI application" and "sudo apt [software name]" approaches to try to install wine. Both have failed. I have failed to get any helpful response after posting detailed error messages in an earlier question. So I sought to post a simpler one about simply starting over.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to provide a definitive answer.  My comment was meant to ask for details so that we can provide a very specific answer would work.  I didn't provide an answer because I didn't want to infer.  I'll remove the downvote if you will fix your question and make it clearer.

Comment: I've tried to install wine in a new instance of 14.04.  I have both 64-bit and 32-bit versions working as separate packages in my current 14.04 install, but it has been a long time since I installed them.    I "think" (it's been days since I started this and have been interrupted many times while working on it) I started by trying to follow installation instructions from WineHQ, which involved using their ppa. I also tried apt-get, Software Center, aptitude, and synaptic.  The last says I have broken packages, but its Broken filter returns none, and "Fix-broken" doesn't indicate anything.

Comment: You have broken packages because you tried to install something that is in conflict with the Libraries of your Ubuntu version.  The developer could have made the system default to replacing your libraries without any consideration for the integrity of the system and my one program work, or it can do as it does by default, not remove your current installed working packages and libraries and let you know it can't continue.  The programs you mentioned are shipped with working versions in the repository. .. (continued)

Comment: ...(continued) I suggest removing what you have already done (from the PPA's) and start out by using the tested versions from the repository.  Without seeing the exact error message, I can't give you the exact command to remove the problem components.   As far as the clean install, run the opposite of what you have done.  Use the commandline to remove the apps that won't install, then remove the PPA's, then install wine with `sudo apt install wine`.  If you add the errors to your question, I'm sur the resolution will be easy for many of us.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate that the pkg manager is doing the safe thing, but it is also operating irrationally by telling me there are broken pkgs, while simultaneously failing to identify them and offering to fix them. I have removed the winehq ppa (long ago) used the command line apt-get to remove, purge, and autoremove wine*, but sudo apt install wine still reports:    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 _wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is not installable_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61037/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-quagmire).

Comment: The only reason I can think that my 64-bit version of Ubuntu thinks it needs wine1.6-i386 is because I followed WineHQ's initial instruction to:   _sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386_ (I thought it odd, but assumed I was getting it straight from Wine authors.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question about removing and cleaning is:

- Remove the offending library components.  By performing in reverse the steps that were done to initiate the various failed installs.

  In this case remove the failed install instances and the failed repository
  `$ sudo apt remove --purge wine`
  `$ sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ --remove`
  `$ sudo apt update`
  `$ sudo apt upgrade`
  `$ sudo apt dist-upgrade`
- Perform fresh install from the default repository then address any dependency issues or errors.
  `$ sudo apt install wine`
  The install process will show where the problems exist and allow the user to address the errors.  This will mean addressing each program one issue at a time.  The immediate error added to your question is the dependent installation of `wine : Depends: wine1.6`.  This is fixed with:
  `$ sudo apt install wine1.6`
    This is where the actual problem lies.  The apt to install the depended package (as per the chat dialog) was the necessary library... the missing/broken package `1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4`.  The specific error lines:
  `The following packages have unmet dependencies:`
  `wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)`
  `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
- Fix each broken or missing dependency one library... one library at a time until there are no more errors.

The repair process can be a timely one.  But the above is the steps.  The package manager actual provides for which packages are depended and need to be fixed in that manner.

Comment: James I'm sorry, I've been away for a couple of days. I have not had a chance to reinstall Ubuntu, but as I had made that decision, I decided to follow your prescription to the letter first. I was extremely surprised to find that the very first command (sudo apt remove --purge wine*) came back with a list of 99 packages to remove, including libreoffice apps, samba, qemu, nfs-common, compiz, and unity.  I'm getting use to apt keeping its reasoning to itself, but removing these make no sense to me whatever. In fact, it looks like, again, apt is consulting something that is misleading it.

Comment: I have clarified that your issue is resolved (or can be resolved by following the steps provided in the answer).  If you have followed those steps you shouldn't have any problems.  The last couple of steps provided to you in the chat resolved your issue.  I had to run an errand.  If you look at the chat I gave you steps, of which I mentioned for you to perform and respond when it was convenient for you.  As far the many Wine items that are installed... they have to be removed to have a clear fresh install.  How to perform fresh was your original question.

Comment: @quagmire No problem.  The time spent (in chat) was to resolve the issue.  I summarized the steps when I returned from my break.  Sorry, I had to interrupt the chat session to run an errand, but I provided the final steps when I returned.  The many Wine components you see is the problem install, which can be remedied by a clean install.  That was your original question... how to cleanup and perform a clean install.  Revisit [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61037/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-quagmire) for more details.  The issue should be resolved.

Comment: @quagmire By the way, I don't think **apt** keeps its reasoning to itself as much as it might appear.  If I could see the output I'm sure it would be rather easy to clarify what it's doing and the suggestions it has.  I'm changing, in this case (for a to the letter step) the first line command to `wine` instead of `wine*`.